# trying to get window width with javascript

Tags: javascript, window, width

Trying to calculate window width but it is not working. My code:

```
var windowWidth = '';
function getWidth() {
  windowWidth = $(window).width() / parseFloat($("body").css("font-size"));
}
```

I want to use `windowWidth` but it will not let me. WHy?

Comment: All you need is  `window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you can just use `window.innerWidth`, but for your specific case it should work just fine with what you have, you just need to call the function you've written:

```
window.addEventListener("load", getWidth);
window.addEventListener("resize", getWidth);
```

Comment: Omg I am stupid thank you and sorry for wasting time

Comment: hah that is ok and no need to be sorry. consider `window.innerWidth` too